# scrapy: yield request from callback called by signal

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I have a spider that scrapes some data and yields an item to the pipeline. The pipeline then checks if this data exists in the database. If it doesn't, it drops the item. The spider is signal connected to invoke a callback on the item_drop signal. I'd like to yield another request to a different url from within item_dropped callback to populate the same item with additional data. If I don't include a yield statement in the callback, it fires, but if I do, it doesn't, and I'm not sure why.

(Simplified for brevity)

MySpider.py:

```
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(MySpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_dropped, signal=signals.item_dropped)
        return spider

[ ...parse start url and yield to pipeline here... ]

def item_dropped(self, item, response, exception, spider,):
        print("ITEM ERROR CAUGHT")
        yield Request(
            url="http://www.example.com/api/data",
            callback=self.parse_request_2,
            cb_kwargs=dict(item=item))
```

MyPipeline.py:

```
def process_item(self, item, spider):

    /* ORM model mapping */
    data = Data(
      name = item['name']
    )

    data_exists = self.session.query(exists().where(Data.name == item['name'])).scalar()


    if data_exists is False:
      raise DropItem("DATA_INCOMPLETE")
```

The reason I'm trying to do it this way is the new objects are constantly added to the first url, so I need to repetitively scrape it, but it doesn't contain all the data I need for that item. I then need to scrape a different url for additional data to be added to that item, but only once, the first time that item is added to the db.

How can I get scrapy to yield another request from within the item_dropped callback? More importantly, am I going about this the right way, or is there a better way to accomplish this? I know I could do the db checks from within the spider and just implement the callback logic there, but I'd prefer to not have both the spider and the pipeline opening db sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot yield requests from that signal.

You must either move your code into a [spider middleware](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html) or move it into a request callback in your spider.

Comment: I believe he can check if signal is made then handle it accordingly

Comment: You cannot yield a request from a signal. At most you could go a hacky way and call `spider.crawler.engine.crawl` or something from it, but a spider middleware is probably a better alternative.